# xml.etree - insert element as a child at specific element

Tags: python, xml.etree

I have a file with some raw data in .txt format and I need to feed the data into a little more structured .xml-document. In Python. My source file has roughly 10000 lines, but for making things easier, I attach only a code with three short lists ("IDs", "Names" and "parent IDs").

The original .txt looks like this:

```
Ac  Value 1
Ac_05   Value 2 Ac
Ac_05_00    Value 3 Ac_05
Ac_15   Value 4 Ac_05
```

If the element has a parent ID (list called pID in my code), then it should be a child of an element that has the same ID as the children's parent ID... hope it makes sense.

I've got as far as this code below:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

IDs = ['Ac', 'Ac_05', 'Ac_05_00', 'Ac_15']
Names = ['Value 1', 'Value 2', 'Value 3', 'Value 4']
pID = ['', 'Ac', 'Ac_05', 'Ac']

# make xml file
Items = ET.Element('Items')

for i in range(len(IDs)):

    if pID[i] in IDs:

        # index of the parent ID
        # IDs.index(pID[i])

        # value of the parent ID
        # IDs[IDs.index(pID[i])]
       
        Item = ET.SubElement(Children, 'Item')

        ID = ET.SubElement(Item, 'ID')
        ID.text = IDs[i]

        Name = ET.SubElement(Item, 'Name')
        Name.text = Names[i]

        Children = ET.SubElement(Item, 'Children')

    else:
        Item = ET.SubElement(Items, 'Item')
            
        ID = ET.SubElement(Item, 'ID')
        ID.text = IDs[i]

        Name = ET.SubElement(Item, 'Name')
        Name.text = Names[i]

        Children = ET.SubElement(Item, 'Children')

tree = ET.ElementTree(Items)
ET.indent(tree, space='\t', level=0)
tree.write('filename.xml', encoding='utf-8')
```

I can't figure out how do I append children to a specific element in .xml. For example the last item with an ID "AC_15" should be a child of "AC". The correct output in .xml should look something like this:

```
<Items>
    <Item>
        <ID>Ac</ID>
        <Name>Value 1</Name>
        <Children>
            <Item>
                <ID>Ac_05</ID>
                <Name>Value 2</Name>
                <Children>
                    <Item>
                        <ID>Ac_05_00</ID>
                        <Name>Value 3</Name>
                        <Children/>                         
                    </Item>
                </Children>
            </Item>
            <Item>
                <ID>Ac_15</ID>
                <Name>Value 4</Name>
                <Children/>
            </Item>
        </Children>
    </Item>
</Items>
```

Does anyone have any tips for a beginner in Python like me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have one big else though the changes to the if part are minor so you should concentrate on the real differences. here the real difference is just the parent element for the item

i made a dict to store all parent elements' children tag and it should be ok. at least it works on your example as intended

```
Items = ET.Element('Items')
elems=dict()
for id_, name, pid in zip(IDs, Names, pID):
    el=ET.Element('Item')
    ET.SubElement(el, 'ID').text = id_
    ET.SubElement(el, 'Name').text = name
    elems[id_]=ET.SubElement(el, 'Children')
    
    if not pid:
        parent=Items
    else:
        parent=elems[pid]
    parent.append(el)
```